# How to close an open xml document in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I tried to use "using" and ".close()" but still I get error when I want to overwritten the file.

As you can see reading and writing the xml file are in a same application but different form that's why I get error every time that I overwritten a file after I read it first

The code below is for form1 which is to create a xml file:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Public Class Form1

Private Sub saveXML_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveXML.Click
    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = False

    ' Initialize the XmlWriter.
    Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(cbFileName.Text, settings)

    With XmlWrt

        ' Write the Xml declaration.
        .WriteStartDocument()

        ' Write a comment.
        .WriteComment("XML Database.")

        ' Write the root element.
        .WriteStartElement("Data")

        ' Start our first person.
        .WriteStartElement("Person")

        ' The person nodes.

        .WriteStartElement("Name")
        .WriteString(txtFullName.Text.ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()

        .WriteStartElement("Email")
        .WriteString(txtEmailAddress.Text.ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()

        .WriteStartElement("Tel")
        .WriteString(txtPhoneNumber.Text.ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()



        ' The end of this person.
        .WriteEndElement()

        ' Close the XmlTextWriter.
        .WriteEndDocument()
        .Close()

    End With

    MessageBox.Show("XML file saved.")
End Sub


Private Sub btnOpenForm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOpenForm.Click
    form2.show()
End Sub
End Class
```

and the code below is for reading it:

```
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (ComboBox1.Text = "") Then

        MessageBox.Show("No file name entered")

    Else

        If (System.IO.File.Exists(ComboBox1.Text.ToString())) Then

            Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(ComboBox1.Text.ToString())

            While (document.Read())

                Dim type = document.NodeType

                If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then

                    If (document.Name = "Name") Then

                        xmlMyName.Visible = True
                        xmlMyName.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                    End If

                    If (document.Name = "Email") Then

                        xmlMyEmail.Visible = True
                        xmlMyEmail.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                    End If

                    If (document.Name = "Tel") Then

                        xmlMyTel.Visible = True
                        xmlMyTel.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                    End If

                    If (document.Name = "Notes") Then

                        xmlMyNotes.Visible = True
                        xmlMyNotes.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                    End If

                End If

            End While

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("The filename you selected was not found.")

        End If

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which exception do you get? Have you tried to put a Using block around the document?

Comment: IOException is the one I get every time. Yes I used Using block but still get the exception

Comment: Can you also show the code that writes the file? I suppose the IOException states that the file is locked or what is the exact error message?

Comment: @Markus sure. I've already edited the post